# How to two subquery division

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two in the following subquery inner select. I would like to division(subquery1/subquery2) two subquery. How do you do it?

`Select subquery1/subquery2,subquery1,subquery2 From.....`

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Well if you have SQL Server 2005 or higher you can do this

```
select
    SQ.s1 / SQ.s2, SQ.s1, SQ.s2
from table as t
    outer apply (select subquery1 as s1, subquery2 as s2) as SQ
```

if you have SQL 2000 then you can use subquery :)

```
select
    SQ.s1 / SQ.s2, SQ.s1, SQ.s2
from
(
    select subquery1 as s1, subquery2 as s2
    from table as t
) as SQ
```